# "Unable to start Oculus XR Plugin" error when starting game in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I am currently developing a 3d VR game for Oculus Quest headset on Unity (v 2019.3.6f1)

Whenever I start the game in Unity editor (by pressing "Play" button) I get the following errors :

```
Unable to start Oculus XR Plugin.  
Failed to load display subsystem. 
Failed to load input subsystem.
```

[image: Console Screenshot]

XR Plugin is installed and updated to the latest version (1.2.0) :

[image: Project Settings Screenshot]

[image: Package Manager Screenshot]

What could be the cause of those errors ? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is there anything you changed in your project recently that could break it? Did you update Unity, or did you install a new plugin or anything from the asset store? Also, does it still build and can you launch it outside the editor?

Comment: Actually, I have never been able to start the game in Unity editor (I had this bug since the beginning). Before, I built&ran directly on Oculus Quest via USB. But I don't have the headset no more, and now I need to be able to run my game on PC for development purposes.
I am able to build, but I can't test launching outside the editor, because - no Oculus Quest :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching problem was resolved by removing Avatar object from my scenes.

Comment: For me there are no Oculus folder or any avatar in the scene on in the assets, and it's not working. Are your sure there is nothing else you have done?

Comment: @Rato Zumbi my problem was in Avatar object in scene, which came from Oculus Integration for Unity package. (this package creates Assets/Oculus folder)

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem. I deleted the Assets/Oculus folder and everything is OK :)

Answer (score 6):

In XR plugin Management (Edit > Project Settings > XR Plugin Management) remove the Oculus Loader from the Plugin Providers in the Windows (PC, Mac & Linux Standalone settings) Tab. List should be empty. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to start the Unity project **after** opening up the oculus app and link, ie:

1. Open Oculus PC App
2. Connect headset
3. Open Unity Project

Answer (score 0):

0: Turn on headset

1: Enable developer and usb-LINK

2: Open Unity project

3: Launch game

Answer (score 0):

I get something similar just after try `MixedReality` on my computer. The issue was that I change the default `OpenXR` runtime. I was able to revert it going to the Oculus app on my PC. `Settings --> General --> OpenXR Runtime --> Set Oculus As Active`

I hope this can help someone